# How does: $n\binom{n-1}{r-1} = r\binom{n}{r}$

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to figure out the identity above though I'm having difficulties towards figuring it out and would kindly appreciate your support!

$n\binom{n-1}{r-1} = r\binom{n}{r}$

What I have tried:
Given that

$$\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\binom{n-1}{r}$$
Then by rearranging for $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$ I get

$$\binom{n}{r}-\binom{n-1}{r}=\binom{n-1}{r-1}$$

Which simplifys to:

$$n\left[\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}-\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-r!)r!}\right]=n\cdot\frac{n!-(n-1)!}{(n-r!)r!}$$

I'm stuck here on how to simply this any further to get the result I'm after.

Comment: This must be trivial if you simply start with $\begin{pmatrix}p\\q\end{pmatrix}=\frac{p!}{(p-q)!q!}$.

Comment: $$
n\binom{n - 1}{r - 1} = \frac{{n(n - 1)!}}{{(r - 1)!(n - r)!}} = \frac{{n!}}{{(r - 1)!(n - r)!}} = r\frac{{n!}}{{r(r - 1)!(n - r)!}} = r\frac{{n!}}{{r!(n - r)!}} = r\binom{n}{r}
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac nr \binom{n-1}{r-1} = \frac nr \frac{(n-1)!}{(r-1)! (n-r)!} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} = \binom nr$$

Answer (score 3):

Of course this just falls out from the identity $\begin{pmatrix}p\\q\end{pmatrix}=\frac{p!}{(p-q)!q!}$. That's no fun (also unenlightening). **Outline** of a "combinatorial" proof:

Say $S=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Let $X$ be the set of all ordered pairs $(s,E)$ such that $s\in S$, $E\subset S$, $E$ has $r-1$ elements, and $s\notin E$. The identity follows by counting the number of elements of $X$ in two different ways.

Comment: I didn't even think about this, this is a great solution!

Answer (score 0):

$\binom{n - 1}{r - 1} = \frac{(n - 1)!}{(r - 1)!(n - r)!}$.

$n*\frac{(n - 1)!}{(r - 1)!(n - r)!} = \frac{n!}{(r - 1)!(n - r)!}.$

Dividing the LHS and RHS by $r$, we want to prove that $\frac{n!}{(r - 1)!(n - r)!(r)} = \binom{n}{r}$.

Expanding the RHS, we get $\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n - r)!}$

Simplifying the LHS, we get $\frac{n!}{r!(n - r)!}$.

RHS = $\frac{n!}{r!(n - r)!}$ = LHS.

So, we are done.

Comment: This is really just a roundabout version of the previous answer...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich sorry about that, I was trying to make my own answer original so I tried to make it different :)

Comment: it's different, but is it better? Or do you agree that the previous version is simpler and clearer?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich the previous solution is much simpler and better but I was trying to state a different way to solve the problem to make it more clear what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

From the formula for binomial coefficients, but the other way: what has to be proved is
$$ \binom nr=\frac nr \binom{n-1}{r-1}.$$
Now, we have
$$\binom nr=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}=\frac nr\frac{(n-1)!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!}=\frac nr\binom{n-1}{r-1}$$
since $\: n-r=(n-1)-(r-1)$.

Comment: This is identical to the accepted answer except that it reads $A=B=C=D$ in place of $D=C=B=A$. What's the point to its existence?

Comment: I just wanted to show a more natural  (at least to my eyes) verification, which starts from $\binom nr$  and arrives at $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$